# seaborn.pairplot : "invalid value encountered in greater" WARNING

Tags: python, seaborn, warnings

Everything seems correct in the plot, neverthenless this warning plays with my confidence on the result. Does someone have any suggestion why this warning pops out?

My DataFrame has mutiple columns all with well defined numerical values (no None or NaN) and the last column called 'Results' is a string column representing the results in form of 'yes' and 'no'  [image]

Comment: How  sure are you there aren't any NaNs? Are you using the latest versions of seaborn, statsmodels and pandas? Can you reproduce the problem using a small dataframe with testdata?

Comment: @JohanC, I read_excel file and somehow one celle of the original excel file was deleted (NaN). Your suggestion was very helpful !